# Identify class of child element and remove an attribute of all matching classes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove an attribute of all elements that match the class of the child of the element that is clicked on.

for example

```
<span class="parent">
    <span class="child1">
        <a href="mylink">text</a>
    </span>
</span>

<span class="child1">
    <a href="mylink">text</a>
</span>
```

I have code that removes the `href` attribute from the element that is clicked on. However, I would like to be able to also remove any elements that have the same link.

I can of course do this be specifying the specific class, but I want the code to find the class of the child of the parent that is clicked, then find any matching classes and remove the href.

In this case, the person would click on `.parent` element, the code would search for the class of the child element, `.child1`, remove the `href` and also remove the `href` of any element that also has a matching class of the child element, `.child1`.

The code would therefore do the same for the following situation

```
<span class="parent">
    <span class="child2">
        <a href="mylink">text</a>
    </span>
</span>

<span class="child2">
    <a href="mylink">text</a>
</span>
```

removing the `href` for all `.child2` classes.

The reason for this is because I need to use this functionality many times, and I do not want to have to write different code each time specifying the class for which to remove the `href`.

I am thinking the construct would be something along the lines of the following, though I am not sure what combinations of jQuery to use to achieve it.

```
$("parant").click(function () {
    $.find(this.childrenClass, function () {
        $.removeAtt("href");   
    });
});
```

Comment: child2 don't have href, is a span.

Comment: The href isn't in a child, it's in a grandchild. Is it always just two levels down, or can it be any number? If it can be any number, how do we find the span whose class we should match on -- is it the top span's child, or the A's parent?

Comment: The above is just an example construct, it doesn't matter too much if it is a child or grandchild, I can have the href in either really. also, the href will always be in the same level down from the parent, either always a child or grandchild, but won't be varied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code should be self-explanatory:

```
$('.parent').click(function() {
    // Get all classes from child elements.
    var classes = $(this).children().map(function() {
        return this.className.split(/\s+/);
    }).get();

    // Find any element having one of those classes, find all `a` children
    // and remove the href attribute.
    $('.' + classes.join(',.')).children('a').removeAttr('href');
});
```

Here I'm just looking for any element having a class in common with any of the children. You will have to adjust the code to restrict it to certain elements if you want to.

The code can also be simplified, depending on your actual markup (i.e. if each parent will only have one child or each child only has one class).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pgQLd/2)

Comment: Thanks. Have looked at the demo and it has the functionality I am looking for. I shall try to apply it to my code and get it to work.

Comment: OK, I have tested the code and it works fine as it is constructed. However, there is a new problem that I should perhaps have highlighted initially. The href of the element is required the first time it is clicked. it is afterwards that it will no longer be required. with the code as it is, it removes all the "href" for matching classes before the initial action on the href takes place. is there a way to exclude the href removal from the clicked element, and only remove from other matching elements?

Comment: Apologies, I had accidentally removed a class required for the execution of the action on the href. This code is working fine now, just as required. Thank you very much. As there is only one child with one class, I do not need to specify. However, should I need to specify a class or which child for something else in the future, how  would you suggest the code be adapted?

Comment: You can pass any selector to `.children()` and search for only specific children. I'd suggest to have a look at the selector page to get an idea of what you can do (it's a lot ;)): http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/. The attribute selectors might be the most useful ones in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".parent").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        klass = $this.children("span").attr("class");
    $("." + klass).find("a").removeAttr("href");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/366cc/

Comment: Thanks. Have looked at the demo and it has the functionality I am looking for. I shall try to apply it to my code and get it to work.

Comment: I have tried the code but it produces a JS error. Can't see a reason for it but perhaps there is something small missing? it is working on the demo page so not sure.

Comment: @user1941653 since the code is pretty simple, it's hard to say why it doesn't work in _your_ code.